# gnuplot: Plotting a function on the surface of a sphere

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap

I have a function, say `f(theta, phi) = sqrt(1 - (sin(theta)*sin(phi))**2) + 5 * sqrt(1 - (sin(theta)*cos(phi))**2)` that I want to plot as a color plot on the surface of a sphere. However, I can't figure out how I have to feed this function into `splot` in order to achieve this without first generating a file with the appropriate values in a table.

How can I get `gnuplot` to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of generating a file, you can use the special filename "++", see `help special`. I think the last example on the [gnuplot demo page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/param.html) has your use case. Simplified with minor modifications:

```
xx(u, v) = cos(v) * cos(u)
yy(u, v) = cos(v) * sin(u)
zz(u, v) = sin(v)
f(theta, phi) = sqrt(1 - (sin(theta)*sin(phi))**2) + 5 * sqrt(1 - (sin(theta)*cos(phi))**2)

set parametric
set isosamples 121, 61
set samples 121, 61
set urange [-pi:pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]

set border 4095
set view equal xyz
set xyplane 0

splot "++" using (xx($1,$2)):(yy($1,$2)):(zz($1,$2)):(f($1,$2)) with pm3d notitle
```

This is the result:

[image: colored sphere]

Please double check whether the definitions of the spherical coordinates match.