# Gnuplot data format for matrices

Tags: gnuplot

I have been looking for documentation and other stackoverflow questions that lay out the basic format that gnuplot uses to interpret data, but nothing really puts out format rules or anything like that, just displays their data and then asks about a specific usecase. Where should I look to get a more detailed description of gnuplot formatting rules and conventions?

I am aware that gnuplot has a lot of docs, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for with a number of google searches and scrolling through the docs themselves. My usecase for this is for generating a matrix in fortran, and then writing to a file.

Comment: Are you talking about text data format or binary format? In gnuplot console have you checked `help matrix`? A matrix consist of several lines (rows) (lineend newline `\n`) which each of them have values separated by a column separator (e.g. whitespace, comma, etc.). Maybe I don't fully understand your problem?!

Comment: In addition to @theozh I'd like to say that gnuplot can handle several different types of data structures (matrices or x-y-z-pairs; no or one or two empty lines in between etc.). So when thinking about how to format the input data you should think how your plot should look like (a function? a surface? a heat map? a histogram?), and then choose the appropriate input data structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper name is, but its a 3d heatmap. I have a cube of data for energy at each point, so each point has an x-y-z and an energy level. I want to store it in a text matrix so that gnuplot can read it and graph it, but I'm not sure if I just need to use gnuplot differently or if theres a standard form to put the data in that gnuplot automatically detects.

It *should* be a surface and very very small energy readings can be disregarded, but the data itself is just a cube, and I don't want to cut the data into a surface myself, I am attempting to have gnuplot to do it.

Comment: @ethanmorton It seems you want to have some sort of 4D plot? Where each data point is positioned at its respective x,y,z coordinates, and is coloured depending on its energy value?
I'd go with a 4 column data structure, each point on a new line: x y z energy. Maybe this question here helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781326/gnuplot-using-splot-with-palette-option-reproduce-smooth-colour-changes

Comment: @Eldrad That does help, thanks. I was able to graph it sensibly by rebuilding the code to write into 4 columns rather than what I was attempting earlier.